# Replace NOTHING with text in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column with some text and another with no information (text formated) and i want to replace the NOTHING with a space if in the Rez column the "1 z" is found.

I have tried

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Obs = REPLACE(Obs,'','Yes')
WHERE Rez LIKE '1 z'
```

with no success... what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple issues.  First `Obs = REPLACE(Obs, '', 'Yes')` won't replace anything if Obs is blank.  Instead use:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Obs = 'Yes'
WHERE Rez LIKE '1 z'
```

Second, are you searching the Rez field for '1 z' of for anything that contains '%1 z%'.  If the first, change your Like to = (although it will work with Like):

```
WHERE Rez = '1 z'
```

If later, add the % to your LIKE clause:

```
WHERE Rez LIKE '%1 z%'
```

Finally, if you only want to update the Obs field if it is blank, add that to your WHERE criteria:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Obs = 'Yes'
WHERE Rez LIKE '%1 z%'
   AND Obs = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Obs = REPLACE(Obs,'','Yes')
WHERE Rez LIKE '%1 z%'
```